# ADT not finding com.google suddenly

Tags: android, windows, adt

After building my application yesterday I started getting errors where ADT was not finding layout ids and ids in general that previously worked, then I noticed that I was getting an error where ever a com.google import was used (com.google can not be resolved). I am not sure what caused it but I tried reinstalling the ADT and the errors are still there, does anyone have an issue like this or know how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Google APIs? It seems that the buildpath has messed up and the Google APIs jars are not there. Try selecting the Google APIs version of your current API level in the project properties and it should work again.

Comment: So I was going to try this and I selected google apis but noticed in the libraries there is an "x" next to pointing to the google maps api

Answer (score 0):

Check for any errors in your layout files, Eclipse is known to delete R.java when there are such errors.  Also try doing project -> clean.